# Convert Currency Text Identifier to Currency Symbol

Tags: php, wordpress

I have field called `salary_currency` in a WordPress database.

In the `salary_currency` table, the value is stored like `USD`,`GBP` etc.

Now I want to get the `currency symbol` like `$` instead of `USD` in the Front-Side.

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store relevant currency in the table. If not, use like the following one.

```
if($salary_currency == 'USD')
$currency_symbol = '$';
else if($salary_currency == 'GBP')
$currency_symbol = '£';
```

You can also try this.

```
$salary_currency = array('$' => 'USD', '£' => 'GBP');
echo $currency_symbol = array_search('USD', $salary_currency);
```

Comment: how to use this code ? 
Where I put this condition block?

Comment: You have stored USD in your table. So need to fetch that first and send to array_search. Need to replace the 'USD' in array_search with your database value.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter automatically the content each time you display it, and from there replace your symbols. In your functions.php add:

```
function change_currency($content) {

    $patterns = array();
    $patterns[0] = '/USD/';
    $patterns[1] = '/EUR/';
    $patterns[2] = '/GBP/';

    $replacements = array();
    $replacements[2] = '€';
    $replacements[1] = '$';
    $replacements[0] = '£';

    $new_content = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $content);

    return $new_content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'change_currency', 6);
```

Comment: If you prefer, instead of making currency arrays and the preg_replace as I wrote, you can use this same function to alter your content and use the native PHP functions linked by @iavery inside…